# Logistic regression: Logit of a quadratic function

Tags: matlab, logistic-regression, glm, glmnet

I have a new question concerning logistic regression. In the usual case the logistic regression for observation i is:

[image]

where p(x) denotes the response variable that is True/False, 1/0 and so on.

Now I have a data set where I want to apply logistic regression (with a lasso / [image: ell_1] penalty), but by construction I know that some variables are correlated. Is there a way of doing a regression such that:

[image]

I work in Matlab using the commands glmnet() and lassoglm() with the family = 'binomial'.

Thank you in advance.